# How to IF check and do multiple things else in CMD

Tags: string, if-statement, cmd, windows-console

===== CMD BATCH FILE=====

I am trying to check a variable=="string" then echo message and run program else it must quit exit 1 if anything else or even empty.

I have tried so much already and used Google, but I just seem to continually receive syntax errors and unexpected at this time errors, CMD is really a struggle to troubleshoot although it is pretty old and yet powerful.

So what i am trying to understand is what is wrong with my brackets or structure, because it is telling me ( was unexpected or syntax error  or was not expected yet... anoying.

My structure like:

```
echo off
if "%1"=="imre" goto imre (
echo found parameter "%1"
) else if NOT %1=="imre" echo you failed
```

just not working; I get

> ( was unexpected

and other syntax errors if I try to tweak this...

All I want is to:    (this is what i have written but it is not working)

```
if %variable%=="hello" (
echo hello is correct 
echo now lets start this program 
start /w excel.exe
) else (
exit 1
)
```

This does not work, and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
this is CMD Batch which is am trying to achieve

Comment: I think you should edit your post to outline the behaviour you're trying to achieve, instead of providing psuedocode. Give a real scenario with the variable and what should happen in all cases.

Comment: I dont know how to edit my post. i am new here.

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11350232/edit) - I've just linked the button under the tags for your post.

Comment: Okay thaks i have just edited it. I am trying to explain what i want and showing what code i have written.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `%variable%` variable actually contain `"hello"` or just, `hello`?

If your parameter doesn't have the quotes, you should use this:

```
if "%variable%"=="hello" (
    echo hello is correct 
    echo now lets start this program 
    start /w excel.exe
) else (
    exit 1
)
```

This way if you pass `Hello` into `%variable%`, you're actually comparing `"hello" == "hello"`.

Comment: Except possibly for the quotation marks, yes.  The code above works for me.

Comment: which dos editor would u recommend , textpad, notepad++ or what?  I thought notepad was ancient... not it is horrible to look at and use i find. thanks for your help, many thanks. I guess i dont know what i was doing before but i swear i was having syntex and unexpected errors it was killing me.  now wheni try , it does indeed work, perhaps what i had i didnt copy and paste correctly in here

Comment: I've always just used Notepad

Comment: I like your website - have not IRCed for a while. my days of ZANet are long gone! I dont mind Undernet or Efnet i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your quotes are inconsistent. But I believe goto is causing the issue, since it comes ahead of the rest of what you want to do.

Try this:

```
echo off
if "%1"=="imre" (
echo found parameter "%1"
goto imre 
) else if NOT "%1"=="imre" echo you failed
```